# How to send credentials to vCenter REST api

Tags: rest, authentication, vsphere, vcenter

When I attempt to hit vCenters auth endpoint in the web browser, i get a 404 and when i try in postman, it can't get any response

I've set up a test environment for vSphere on my mac using vmware fusion. I have 1 ESXi instance hosting an instance of vCenter. While trying to make rest calls to vCenter on Postman, it says I could not get any response.

```
https://{vCenterIP}/rest/com/vmware/cis/session
```

is what I'm trying to hit.

it appears that the expected result is the following json object

```
{
    "value": "dfbERG34ge24SSEfg"
}
```

the value being the authentication token. What I am receiving from the web browser is

```
{
  "name": "com.vmware.vapi.rest.httpNotFound",
  "localizableMessages": [
    {
      "defaultMessage": "Not found.",
      "id": "com.vmware.vapi.rest.httpNotFound"
    }
  ],
  "majorErrorCode": 404
}
```

Again, I'm not getting any response from Postman for any of the vCenter REST enpoints

Answer (score 1):

What version of vCenter are you using? The REST API endpoint is only available for vSphere 6.5 and newer.

If you're on version 6.5 or newer, can you log in to the vCenter through the UI?

I would also suggest using the Postman collections that are available as part of the vSphere Automation SDK for REST, if you haven't found them already: https://github.com/vmware/vsphere-automation-sdk-rest/tree/master/samples/postman

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. You can fix this issue by turning off ssl certificate verification in postman settings.

SSL certificate setting in postman:
[image: SSL CERTIFICATE SETTING POSTMAN]